# Are there any recommended puppet modules, for creating Kafka topics?

Tags: puppet, apache-kafka

Are there any recommended puppet modules, for creating Kafka topics?

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly are you looking for but there are basically couple of alternatives ..

1) Use the [console script](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart) shipped with the default distribution, allows you to create topics from command prompt 

2) The [Java Api](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#api) provided by Kafka for achieving the same

Comment: Ha ha... I know :-) 
I wanted to use puppet... never mind (I have written one & I will upload it). 

p.s. thanks for your answer.

Comment: there no such thing available unfortunately .. would be nice to see some one working on the same.. do keep us posted this could help a lot other people .. :)